# SSIS expression flat file connection

Tags: variables, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am new to *SSIS* and I am just looking at an existing package. In one of the Sequence container there is a `Script Task` component which read the source file attributes using a C# code. I can see all the variable (user) declared for ReadWriteVariables but I can’t find variable declared anywhere for the ReadOnlyVariable which is `$Package::fileName`

I can see the connection for source file has Expression  `Connection String  =$Package::fileName`

Where is this `$Package::fileName` variable is created? I need to create another package in the same solution but I can’t see `$Package::fileName` in my package. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a package parameter, not a variable.  For information about package parameters, this link might be helpful:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/16/configuring-projects-and-packages-using-parameters.aspx